# Subjunctive mood usage in Conditionals

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives, conditionals

> India’s concern is that **if it takes** a decision that irks Generals in Myanmar, China **would** get closer to the junta and use the opportunity to hurt India’s interests in Myanmar.

I studied that **would** is used in subjunctive or hypothetical sentences. But here, Is the first part of the sentence “India’s concern is that **If it takes a decision**”  hypothetical? I don’t think so. Then why would is used in later part?

Comment: Your tenses are inconsistent. Use EITHER *If X **takes** a step, Y **will** react*, OR *If X **took** a step, Y **would** react.* Or go for the "full-blown" subjunctive *If X **were to take** a step,...* which is still "irrealis, hypothetical", so you'd still follow it with *...Y **would** react.*

Comment: Would you mind saying difference between “if X took a step” and “if X were to take a step” ?

Comment: For the meaning we're discussing here, *if X took a step* and *if X were to take a step* are equivalent and interchangeable (but the shorter first version is *far* more common, especially in informal contexts). But whereas the second (explicitly "subjunctive") form can *only* refer to an unreal / hypothetical future possibility, the "Simple Past" version could refer to a ***past*** action (where speaker simply doesn't know whether X took that step of not, in the past).

Comment: ...note that the explicit subjunctive form has been declining for centuries. Don't use it ay more than you have to.

Answer (score 1):

> India’s concern is that if it takes a decision that irks Generals in Myanmar, China would get closer to the junta and use the opportunity to hurt India’s interests in Myanmar.

Q. But here, Is the first part of the sentence “India’s concern is that If it takes a decision” hypothetical? I don’t think so. Then why would is used in later part?

---

**Making hypotheses**

A. The above is a conditional sentence. "***if** it takes a decision....China **would** get"* and also a  hypothetical one. Therefore it should have been written as  "***if** it made/took a decision....China **would** get"*

**hypothetical** [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hypothetical?q=%20hypothetical); adjective; imagined or **suggested but not necessarily real or true**:

> (Some conditional clauses are like hypotheses, so we use past tense forms).
> We use past tense forms to make suggestions about what might happen in the future:

Example

> If we invited John, Mary would bring Angela.
> Ref [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/verbs-in-time-clauses-and-if-clauses)

Comment: I don't think you've fully understood or fully answered the OP's question - which, effectively, is why the writer said "if it **takes**..., China **would**..." where we would expect to read either "if it **took**...., China **would**..." or "if it **takes**..., China **will...**".  Your example uses the past tense in the condition clause ("if we invited"), whereas the OP's example uses the present tense ("takes") but combines that with "would".

Comment: @rjpond, sorry I stand corrected. I thought the base question was "Subjunctive mood usage in Conditionals"  with the secondary question "Then why would is used in later part"? I have now address your concerns and edited the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the sentence “India’s concern is that if it makes a decision” IS hypothetical.  India might make a certain decision, or it might not.  So "China would" (or "could") is appropriate.  You could use "China will . . ."

(Also, "makes a decision" instead of "takes a decision" would be more common.)

Comment: So both "India’s concern is that if it makes a decision" and "India’s concern is that if it made a decision" are hypothetical???